# Splitting and manipulating lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following lists:

```
id = {5, 11, 17, 24, 25, 31, 32, 33, 37, 38, 39, 40}

values = {0.00390625, 0.00292969, 0.00769043, 0.00350189, 0.316406,0.00787926, 0.237305, 0.207642, 0.0118189, 0.0945511, 0.0709133, 0.0354567}

a = {5., 7., 8., 10., 5., 11., 7., 8., 12., 10., 11., 12.}

b = {-4., -4., -3., -3., 4., -2., 4., 3., -1., 3., 2., 1.}
```

which can be visualized below. Also shown is what I wish to achieve.

I need to split the data in two: One part where b is negative, and one part where b is positive. Moreover, each of the two parts obtained are finally sorted in ascending order by a (or aneg and apos in the wording of the image).

What is a good approach to this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{neg, pos} = 
 SortBy[#, #[[3]] &] & /@ 
  SplitBy[SortBy[Transpose[{id, values, a, b}], Last], Sign[#[[4]]]&]

TableForm /@ {neg, pos}
```

> [image]

Comment: this gives an error for me: Part::partw: Part 4 of #1 does not exist.   Set::shape: Lists {neg,pos} and {{{5,0.00390625,5.,-4.}},{{11,0.00292969,7.,-4.}},{{17,0.00769043,8.,-3.}},{{24,0.00350189,10.,-3.}},{{31,0.00787926,11.,-2.}},{{37,0.0118189,12.,-1.}},{{40,0.0354567,12.,1.}},{{39,0.0709133,11.,2.}},{{33,0.207642,8.,3.}},{{38,0.0945511,10.,3.}},{{25,0.316406,5.,4.}},{{32,0.237305,7.,4.}}} are not the same shape.

Comment: @user120911 sorry, in the copy/paste process I missed the last three symbols of the code :) fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`GroupBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html) as follows:

```
grouped = GroupBy[Transpose[{id, values, a, b}], 
  Sign@*Last, 
  SortBy[#[[3]] &]]
```

[image]

```
Row[Grid[#, Dividers -> All]& /@ Values @ grouped, Spacer[20]]
```

[image]